# How to fix "numpy.core._multiarray_umath is not found"?

Tags: python, numpy

I am not able to load the addons *Construction Lines* and *Precision Drawing Tools* because *"numpy.core._multiarray_umath is not found"*. I saw that similar questions has been asked but I found no response. Would a virtual environment solve the problem?

If yes, how to make it?

I checked many tutorials but I am still not able to figure it all.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What version of Blender are you using? Have you changed anything with the Python version that is included with it?

Comment: I have Blender 3.4.1 and I did not change anything with the Python included. After many trying, I finally uninstalled numpy from my system and the addons functioned normally. Things like that are not supposed to occur . Are-they not? Thanks for asking.

Comment: I'm glad that you got it working. As you said, things like your having to uninstall numpy from your system are not supposed to happen, as far as I know. I don't know much, but I believe that Blender only uses whatever Python there is in the Blender Python folder.